# Change a specific ImageButton using a variable

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hey I need to change the url of certain image buttons, I have the number of the ImageButton ID I need to change stored in a variable, Can I somehow do it?

Comment: Did you try anything? How should we know which properties you want to change if you don't know it yourself?

Comment: You definitely need to add more details here, like the code, how the buttons are created, when would you liek to change their properties. The best answer you can get without all this is just "use FindControl"